How to create search in ui/shadcn?
I try to use this https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/command for searching functionality but the problem is that it doesn't overlap the text.

as you can see in the image. The dropdown doesn't overlap the test here text. I just want to create a dropdown list when I search for a value. I'm checking the documentation. It doesn't have an option. I'm not sure if this is applicable to this library.
I'm new on this library ui.shadcn

Future reference, you might want to include some code; it's kind of hard to spot an issue this way.
I had no issue implementing this with the CommandSearch.tsx looking like this:
interface ICommandProps {
  commands: { value: string; label: string }[];
}

export default function CommandSearch({ commands }: ICommandProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleValueChange = (value: string) => {
    setInputValue(value);
    setOpen(!!value);
  };

  const filteredCommands = Array.isArray(commands)
    ? commands.filter((command) =>
        command.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
      )
    : [];
  console.log("filteredCommands", filteredCommands);
  return (
    <Command className="rounded-lg border shadow-md">
      <CommandInput
        placeholder="Type a command or search..."
        onValueChange={handleValueChange}
      />
      {
        <CommandList>
          {open &&
            filteredCommands.length > 0 &&
            filteredCommands.map((command) => (
              <CommandItem key={command.value} value={command.value}>
                {command.label}
              </CommandItem>
            ))}
        </CommandList>
      }
    </Command>
  );
}
}

And the next page looking like this:
export default function Page() {
  const commands = [
    { value: "calendar", label: "Calendar" },
    { value: "search-emoji", label: "Search Emoji" },
    { value: "calculator", label: "Calculator" },
  ];

  return <CommandSearch commands={commands} />;
}


for example, consider the bellow component:
 import {
    Command,
    CommandEmpty,
    CommandGroup,
    CommandInput,
    CommandItem,
    CommandList,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import { UserCardProps } from "../cards/UserCards";
import { useState } from "react";


interface SearchInputProps {
    searchList: UserCardProps[];
}

export function FilterSearchInput({ searchList }: SearchInputProps) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    return (
        <Command inputMode="text" className="bg-black w-[250px] rounded-lg  border-gray-400 text-txtWhite relative">
            <CommandInput className="h-full" value={value} onValueChange={(e) => setValue(e)} placeholder="search..." />
            {value && <CommandList className="border-none">
                <CommandEmpty>No results found</CommandEmpty>
                <CommandGroup heading="Users">
                    {searchList.map(item => {
                        return (<CommandItem key={item.id}>
                            <span>{item.name}</span>
                            <span>{item.id ?? ''}</span>
                        </CommandItem>)
                    })}
                </CommandGroup>
            </CommandList>}
        </Command>
    )
}

